# Equally divide task to threads according to hardware concurrency

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm trying to run this simple program and wondering why the output is coming wrong. The code queries for hardware concurrency, then tries to launch that amount of threads and do some task. To stub that task, I'm writing to individual elements of already resized vector, but the result is still coming wrong -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

void myMethod(std::vector<int> &v, int threadNumber) {
    for(int i = threadNumber - 1; i < v.size(); i+= threadNumber) {
        v[i] = threadNumber;
    }
}

int main() {
    const auto numThread = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.resize(100, 0);

    if(numThread < 2) {
        std::cout << "Not running\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> vT;
    for(int i = 1; i <= numThread; ++i) {
        vT.emplace_back(myMethod, std::ref(vec), i);
    }
    for(auto &t: vT) { t.join(); }


    for(const auto &i: vec) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output comes as -

```
1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 4
```

but I was expecting - `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ...`

Comment: In `myMethod(...)`, did you mean `i+= std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`?

Comment: Implementation note: There are many possible partitions of `v`, but the two most natural one are this (striping, size=1) and dividing `v` in `numThreads` partitions of approximately `v.size()/numThreads` each. The downside of striping is that adjacent elements of `v` may share a cache line, which will then be contested. By using fewer, bigger chunks, there's less cache contention as most adjacent elements will be processed by the same CPU core.

Comment: @MSalters thankyou but I couldn't understand how would I divide like that. If numThreads was 2, it would be very easy - send exactly half to 1st thread and rest to others, but as numThreads go bigger and numTasks go bigger like 100tasks/8threads, it is harder to divide like that for me :/. I mean till what tasks should I send to 1st thread and then 2nd thread ..., I feel hard to visualize that. I'm not a CS Major and still learning programming, so any help would be recommend.

Comment: Easy. 0-12 to the first thread, 13-24 to the second, 25-37 to the third etc. Thread N gets items  N*100/8 to (N+1)*100/8.

Answer (score 1):

In your `myMethod` function, you're increasing variable `i` with wrong amount -

```
void myMethod(std::vector<int> &v, int threadNumber) {
    for(int i = threadNumber - 1; i < v.size(); i+= threadNumber) {
        v[i] = threadNumber;
    }
}
```

should actually be -

```
void myMethod(std::vector<int> &v, int threadNumber) {
    const auto numThread = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    for(int i = threadNumber - 1; i < v.size(); i+= numThread) {
        v[i] = threadNumber;
    }
}
```